# Oracle sql command for selecting more than one value in like

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a query in Oracle in which i need to enter more than one parameter in like clause.. It can be :

```
Select id from  student where name like 'Tom'
union
Select id from  student where name like 'Amy'
union
Select id from  student where name like 'Jany'
```

this will make more queries i want some query like ...

```
Select id from  student where name like ('Tom','Amy','Jany')
```

Is it possible in Oracle11g or something similar to this query

Comment: No point in using the "like" operator if you are not using wildcards (%, _). Just use "=", or "in": name in ('Tom','Amy','Jany')

Comment: Nothing like `like any (...)` is possible directly but there's very similar solution based on `exists` and concatenated like expression, see my answer under linked question. (You can see also the Sokrates` solution at at AskTom.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle REGEXP_LIKE works here

**REGEXP_LIKE**

```
Select id from  student where REGEXP_LIKE(name,'(Tom|Amy|Jany)')
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot use `IN` for `LIKE` condition.

Simple way is to use `OR`but which is quite time tedious to code.

```
SQL>select id from student where name like '%Tom%' or name like '%Amy%' or name like '%Janny%';
```

Reference:[AskTom:Like Operator with IN clause](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1675747400346669051)

Comment: I got a new answer i am sharing it